# php session have to start but when it starts give exception

Tags: php, session

i have a site, with many tabs , when i open any tab i want to get some data from session, but that data can't be got without `session_start();` and when i put `session_start()` , an exception thrown tell me that the session is already starts

this is the exception

```
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
```

Comment: You should show the code that is failing and the exception that it produces. The section of code posted should be the smallest snippet of code which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to see if the session is set before starting the session.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can begin with

```
if(!$_SESSION) {
    session_start();
}
```

or,

```
@session_start();
```

The "@" supresses errors.

Comment: Did you add the "$" in front of that, like `$_SESSION?`

Comment: I agree with Jonathan. You shouldn't suppress errors, deal with them.

Comment: Also, just a note: (!$_SESSION) checks if the session is null, not if it exists or not. (!isset($_SESSION)) checks if the session exists. You could technically have a $_SESSION that is null and still a valid session.